# Determine the difference between time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that consists of date and time column like showed below, with the date format (MM/DD/YYYY);

```
|Date    | Time   |
|--------|--------|
|1/1/2019|1200hrs |
|1/1/2019|1300hrs |
|1/1/2019|1400hrs |
|1/2/2019|1200hrs |
|1/2/2019|1300hrs |
|1/2/2019|1400hrs |
|1/2/2019|1700hrs |
```

I want to generate another column that shows the difference between each time like the dataframe shown below,

```
|Date    | Time   |Time difference(mins)|
|--------|--------|---------------------|
|1/1/2019|1200hrs |-                    |
|1/1/2019|1300hrs |60                   |
|1/1/2019|1400hrs |60                   |
|1/2/2019|1200hrs |-                    |
|1/2/2019|1300hrs |60                   |
|1/2/2019|1400hrs |60                   |
|1/2/2019|1700hrs |180                  |
```

The time difference should be calculated on the same date.
Can anyone give me some idea of how to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with convert to datetimes, last convert timedeltas to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and last to minutes by division of `60`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y%H%Mhrs')
df['Time difference(mins)'] = df.groupby('Date')['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60)
print (df)
       Date                Time  Time difference(mins)
0  1/1/2019 2019-01-01 12:00:00                    NaN
1  1/1/2019 2019-01-01 13:00:00                   60.0
2  1/1/2019 2019-01-01 14:00:00                   60.0
3  1/2/2019 2019-01-02 12:00:00                    NaN
4  1/2/2019 2019-01-02 13:00:00                   60.0
5  1/2/2019 2019-01-02 14:00:00                   60.0
6  1/2/2019 2019-01-02 17:00:00                  180.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to ask what if there is a time like 1230hrs, 1130hrs, etc.?

Comment: I got an error;
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: @Jason - There is also changed first line of code? Converting to datetimes?